# How to change order of TTabSheets in an inherited TPageControl?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Usually what I do to change the order of TabSheets in a PageControl is:

1. Right-click on the Form and choose "View as Text"
2. Manually edit the source DFM to put the TabSheets in the desired order
3. Right-click on the source and choose "View as Form"

Although it's a hassle, this procedure works.

But now, I have a new situation.  I'm using a Form that inherits from another Form that already has a PageControl with 2 TabSheets. I need to add a third tab, but this needs to be the second in order. No matter what I do in the DFM source code, I can't change the second inherited TabSheet to be the third page in the PageControl.

Is there an alternative way to achieve changing the order of TabSheets in a inherited Form?

Comment: Maybe it's easiest in Code: Set PageIndex in the constructor (or FormCreate).

Comment: @UliGerhardt This did the trick ! Please post as answer so i can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's easiest to handle this in code: Set the TabSheet's [`PageIndex`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet.PageIndex) property in the Form's constructor or `OnCreate` event.